# $ABC$ is a triangle with $a,b$ and $c$ are the opposite sides of the angles. Let $(a^2+b^2):c^2=2019:1$, find $(\cot A+\cot B+\cot C:\cot A +\cot B)$

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area, ratio

$ABC$ is a triangle with $a,b$ and $c$ are the opposite sides of the angles. Let $(a^2+b^2):c^2=2019:1$, find $(\cot A+\cot B+\cot C:\cot A +\cot B)$

My attempt:
\begin{align*}
a^2+b^2-2ab\cos C&=c^2\\
2019-\dfrac{2ab\cos C}{c^2}&=1\\
1009&=\dfrac{ab\cos C}{c^2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}\cot\alpha}{\cot\alpha+\cot\beta}=1+\frac{\frac{\cos\gamma}{\sin\gamma}}{\frac{\sin\gamma}{\sin\alpha\sin\beta}}=1+\frac{\cos\gamma\sin\alpha\sin\beta}{\sin^2\gamma}=$$
$$=1+\frac{\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}\cdot\frac{2S}{bc}\cdot\frac{2S}{ac}}{\frac{4S^2}{a^2b^2}}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a^2+b^2}{2c^2}=1010.$$

Comment: Sorry, but isn't the last line be $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a^2+b^2}{2c^2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2019}{2}=\frac{1010}{1}$

Comment: You are right, @Ken. I fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Using cosine & sine formula of Triangle,

$$\dfrac{\cot C}{\cot B+\cot A}=\dfrac{\dfrac{(a^2+b^2-c^2)2R}{2abc}}{\dfrac{2R(c^2+a^2-b^2+b^2+c^2-a^2)}{2abc}}=\dfrac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2c^2}=\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{c^2}-\dfrac12=?$$